# Understanding and writing RPM spec files

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to write spec files to generate rpm files using a packet manager.

In the sample spec files on the internet under the "%file" section there are tags such as "%{_bindir}".

Could some please tell me if this is a variable and if it is where is it saved. If not then what does it represent.I would be grateful if you could point me towards a resourse or help me with the answer.

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package → » To make your package less sensitive to upstream changes, declare all files within a directory to be owned by the package with a pattern match: %{_bindir}/* «

Comment: Here's a list of all RPMMacros https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:RPMMacros.

Comment: See [**Maximum RPM**](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/), **Chapter 13** in particular.